# R: package depends on locally installed package

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am working on two separate, but related packages.
Among a bunch of other functions flowerR contains the following generic function `show_match`:

```
show_match <- function(x, ...) {
   UseMethod("show_match") 
}


#' @export
#' @rdname show_match 
show_match.flowerClass <- function(x, ...) {
   # do a bunch of stuff and generate some output 
}
```

Package `flowerR` is installed locally on my machine, in "C:/my_R_packages", it loads fine into R (`library(flowerR`) and works fine by itself.

In package `treeR` I want to build on this generic method for a second class:

```
#' @export
#' @rdname show_match 
show_match.treeClass <- function(x, ...) {
   # do a bunch of stuff and generate some output 
}
```

In order for R to be able to find the generic function, I included

```
Depends: flowerR
```

in the `treeR` DESCRIPTION file. However, when I check `treeR` (using `devtools::check`), I receive the error: `Error : package 'flowerR' required by 'treeR' could not be found`. This boggles me, because R has no problem attaching flowerR when using `library(flowerR)`.

How can I make this work?

BTW, what does work fine is:

```
library(flowerR)
class(x)   # [1] "treeData"
show_match(x)   # works fine, with flowerR loaded, the method in treeR runs perfeclty
```

so, when `flowerR` is loaded into R interactively, all works well. Now, the question is how to make this happen when `flowerR` is not attached by hand.

Comment: Did you put `floweR` in import statement anywhere in your oxygen docs, or if not using oxygen, in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: Yes, I tried that adding `@import flowerR` into a file (`aaa.R`) where I define the package. This generates the error `Namespace dependency not required: 'flowerR'`. The alternative `@import flowerR show_match` yields this same error. This makes some sense, because R does not necessarily know that the generic function resides in `flowerR`.